# A good monospaced font to go with Computer Modern font

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I am not that experienced with pairing fonts but am wondering if one could direct on which is a good *monospaced* font to go with [Computer Modern](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46663/is-computer-modern-a-high-quality-font), or at least the principles one could use to figure out what a good pairing would be given that font. The font [Inconsolata](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inconsolata) has been [recommended](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50812/26407) but it doesn't pair very well. I have just found [Computer Modern Typewriter](https://www.checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/#typewriter), but not sure if that would be a good choice. An example of Computer Modern is below.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Computer_modern_sample_text.svg]
[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/CMU_Fonts.png/800px-CMU_Fonts.png]

Comment: " I have just found Computer Modern Typewriter, but not sure if that would be a good choice" – this is also by Donald Knuth, the designer of CM (and the typesetting system TeX, for which *all* of these fonts were designed). It's one superfamily; so yeah, definitely a 'good choice'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a look to all [this big list](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/classification/monospaced) at fontsquirrel.com,
the only monospaced font that I think fits better with the Computer Modern Roman is [Luxi Mono](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Luxi-Mono).

**Common points:**

- The structural basis of the characters is the same as a Roman family
- It has similar but rectangular serif, it's a Slab Serif family
- It has strokes modulation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One good monospaced family I've used recently is the [Decima Mono Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tipografiaramis/decima-mono-pro/).

[image: Decima Mono Pro]

[image: Decima Mono Pro]